# If I add one unit of angular momentum to two different particles, can I end up with the same particle

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-spin

Suppose I have $B$ and $B^*$ mesons. I will add one unit of orbital angular momentum to each of them. The $B$ meson will become an excited state of its original self and transition into a $B_1$ meson instead. But in the case of the $B^*$ meson, it is more complicated. As it already has a spin value of $1$, it can combine with the added angular momentum to form one of three new particles (with spin $0,1,2$). Looking at the pdg data, I see that the only bottom meson with spin $1$ is the $B_1$ particle.

This leads me to believe that exciting a $B^*$ meson by adding precisely one unit of orbital momentum could allow it to transition into a $B_1$ meson. This means that the $B$ and $B^*$ meson could transition into the same particle.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Hint write the parities of constituents and products in your contemplated reactions. pretend you are combining the initial mesons with a ρ.

Comment: @CosmasZachos If I consider parity of $B^* + \rho \to B$, I see that $(-1)(-1) = (+1)$. Everything seems to be okay.

Comment: But B is a pseudoscalar, not a scalar.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I believe I made a typo. I have updated my question. I wanted to look at the case where the new spin was $1$ and not $0$. My apologies.

Comment: In that case, adding $1^-$ to a $0^-$ or else $1^-$ can result in a common $1^+$ as you conjecture...